# Use specific CSS for specific view in MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

How can I use a specific css file for only one particular view, so that the rest of the website uses the Site.css but one particular view uses my Custom.css file?

Comment: Write the code in a manner that allows that the view loads the CSS file you want.

Comment: Why does it need to be a separate file? Could you just namespace the view in your main CSS file? e.g. add an ID to the wrapping div of your view and treat it as a separate section? Otherwise, I don't know; I think CSS files have to be declared in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

Comment: Put the default css file location in the ViewBag in `_viewStart` file, and overwrite that variable in your specific view.

Answer (score 0):

In the code block at the start of your view, declare the layout variable as a different source path, ie:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "About"; //This is the about page
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AboutLayout.cshtml";
}
```